# Text extraction using itext7: garbage characters for some pdf documents

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a problem extracting text from pdf documents using iText7. For documents coming from a specific source textRenderInfo.GetText() returns only garbage chars (0xfdff) in the event handler of my extraction strategy:

```
internal class CustomExtractionStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
{
    public virtual void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (!type.Equals((object)EventType.RENDER_TEXT))
        {
            return;
        }

        var textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo)data;
        bool currentResultEmpty = _result.Length == 0;
        bool isInNewLine = false;

        var baseline = textRenderInfo.GetBaseline();
        var startPoint = baseline.GetStartPoint();
        var  endPoint = baseline.GetEndPoint();

        var currentText = textRenderInfo.GetText(); // returns garbage for specific pdfs

        // further processing below
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the way text/glyph encoding words in PDF but I try to give some details when comparing the problematic pdfs with an example where extraction works. For the pdfs with issues:

- `textRenderInfo.gs.font` is MS-UIGothic
- `textRenderInfo.gs.font.fontProgram.codeToGlyph` contains only mapping (key: 0 to a Glyph with width 1000, unicode -1, code 0)
- `textRenderInfo.gs.font.fontProgram.unicodeToGlyph` contains no records

These are the most obvious discrepancies. If there's any thing else I should look out for please let me know. I would have provided an example of the PDF in question but it might have sensitive information that I must not disclose.

Note: the PDFs can be correctly read in Acrobat Reader and I can copy text from the reader into notepad. Other libraries (pdfium based or ports of PDFBox) can properly extract text from the document. So I think the document as such is "valid".

If this is a known issue for iText7, is there any workaround (other than using a different library altogether)?

#### Update

With the link provided in the comment and the following code (in addition to the custom extraction strategy snippet shown above) I get garbage chars [see VS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqKFs.png):

```
    internal class PdfExtractor
    {
        internal void ExtractFromPath(string path)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
            var document = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(reader);
            for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= document.GetNumberOfPages(); pageNum++)
            {
                var page = document.GetPage(pageNum);

                string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, new CustomExtractionStrategy());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share an example PDF from that specific source?

Comment: This is an example that has this problem: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gOymXPwAKxujn0gUj3z5C60xtMqV91Q/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @mkl pls see uploaded example.

Comment: pdfs can embed only the glyphs from a font that are actually used. And those glyphs can be renumbered.

Comment: @KJ please see my update. Are you suggesting I should retrieve the text not using `textRenderInfo.GetText()` but through some alternative method? Which one? How would I recognize that I have to use an alternative approach for a particular document (unless that alternative approach works for all sorts of documents). Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Hm ... what does this mean in context of using iText7 to extract text from a PDF? I would rather not want to do text extraction myself - that's why I'm using libraries (and we actually purchased an iText7 license - but since our support contract expired I'm using SO for questions).

Comment: The information for text extraction in the definition of the used font in the PDF are missing (or invalid): There is a **ToUnicode** map but it contains no **bfchar** or **bfrange** sections (which are the relevant sections for **ToUnicode** maps); instead **cidrange** sections are used (which are irrelevant in **ToUnicode** maps). Furthermore, the encoding is **Identity-H** which only indicates that we have a double-byte encoding. Thus, there is no valid information for text extraction according to the text extraction algorithm given in the PDF spec.

Comment: In the case at hand one would get the correct text by assuming an UTF-16 encoding. But that is not the most usual case for **Identity-H**, so assuming something different generally makes sense, but in your document it results in garbage output.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for the thorough analysis. In essence this means that this document is not completely valid (at least for extraction) but it looks like some other libraries (and Acrobat Reader) have found and implemented ways to deal with deviations from the standard while iText7 hasn't gone down that road. So if I need to ensure extraction also for this kind of documents I have to use another library.

Comment: Thanks @KJ for the suggestion - in essence it means I have to use another library then.

Comment: *"In essence this means that this document is not completely valid (at least for extraction)"* - Yes, the cmap given as **ToUnicode** map is not built for that purpose. *" it looks like some other libraries (and Acrobat Reader) have found and implemented ways to deal with deviations from the standard while iText7 hasn't gone down that road"* - ... with ***this*** deviation. There are other deviations that iText 7 may cope with better than others.

Comment: *"So if I need to ensure extraction also for this kind of documents I have to use another library."* - different libraries have their own strengths and weaknesses. But indeed, while iText is a general purpose PDF library with text extraction being just one feature, there are other libraries and services that are built solely for the purpose of text extraction. If such special purpose libraries were not at least a bit better at their specialty than a general purpose library, one would wonder what they were good for...

Comment: @mkl - I completely agree. Every choice will be a compromise and I have to find the one that fits best to the use case (and type of documents) I have. We use iText7 in other contexts successfully since years (PDF creation), that's why it was the go-to candidate for text extraction as well. And I may run into other PDFs that are not handled well by any alternative library that I may end up with.